# How to enter different color String in UITextView use different languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

**I want to choose the color and then change the text color of the UITextView currently entered use different languages**

But I encountered the following problems

**1.Can not find the last entered text**

[Demo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrdmH.png)

For example, in this case, I have not yet confirmed the entered text, but it has already been executed method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *) textView shouldChangeTextInRange: (NSRange)range replacementText: (NSString *)text
```

I guess it is the first to create a range of characters, confirm the choice of input words, and then replace it

However, I do not need this input character range, which affects the NSRange parameters I need to change the color of the word

So I changed the color function into the `textViewDidChange` method, but it caused me to delete crashes

**2.Why other languages except English do not execute method**

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)text
```

This is my demo link https://github.com/xueyefengbao/Demo.git

Who can help me solve the problem or modify the features I mentioned in my demo?

Thank you very much :)

**After trungduc's suggestion, I changed the code**

**Still Found some small problems**

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge8Oa.png)

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtD3U.png)

**Can not enter continuously**

[Continuous input error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHsjZ.gif)

Comment: Does your problem contain case when pasting text?

Comment: @trungduc If you can, it is best

Comment: I fixed it without pasting. But you also need in case pasting, it’s much more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your questions.

- **Can not find the last entered text** - Seem like you forgot to reset `lastRange` before deleting. But you don't use it any more so we can ignore it.
- **Why other languages except English do not execute method** It's because in your language, with some case when you enter a character, it doesn't alway add a character to string. Actually, it replaces the last character with another one. It makes `lastRange` you get from `shouldChangeTextInRange` is out of range of current text on textView. My solution is before using `[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:self.currentColor range:self.lastRange];`, you should check and correct `self.lastRange`.

You can try by replacing your methods with the code below.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if (text.length == 0) {
        self.lastRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0); // Reset lastRange when deleting
        return YES;
    }
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }

    BOOL result = [self doesFit:textView string:text range:range];

    if (result) {
        self.lastRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, text.length);
    }
    return result;
}

- (void)resetCorrectFontStyle:(UITextView *)textView  {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = (textView.textContainer.size.height - (textView.font.lineHeight)*23)/23;
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, textView.attributedText.length)];

    // Check if lastRange can't be used with current text, correct location of lastRange
    if (_lastRange.length + _lastRange.location > textView.text.length) {
      _lastRange = NSMakeRange(_lastRange.location - 1, _lastRange.length);
    }

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:self.currentColor range:self.lastRange];

    _keyboardTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found some minor problems

When I switch to Japanese, and then enter a m, it will enter the characters, and can not be deleted, it is not a character but a Part of alphabet

Comment: @zzx It works perfectly with my language but I don't know how Japanese keyboard work so i think you have to modify a little to work with Japanese. Good luck ;)

Comment: I've updated the screenshot at the bottom of my question, you can take a look

Comment: @zzx i think problem is because you are using `attributedText`. With `text` it will work normally but you can't change color of text if you use `text`. It will be a big problem for you ;)

Comment: This really is a big problem, but I think that only using attributedText to complete my function

In addition, I found that continuous input is also a problem (and update the screenshot above)

Comment: I have no idea for this problem ;)